# Gulp task doesn't produce anything

Tags: gulp

I started to learn gulp. When I run my gulp tasks on console, console doesn't show any error, however, doesn't produce anything.

I am pretty sure I am missing something in my gulpfile.js

**I am trying to resize my images with gulp-image-resize.**
Here is my gulpfile:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imageResize = require('gulp-image-resize');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const changed = require('gulp-changed');

const imgPaths = {
    src:'./img/**/*.{jpg}',
    dist:'./img/responsive/'
}

gulp.task('resize-min', function() {
    gulp.src(imgPaths.src)
    .pipe(changed(imgPaths.dist))
    .pipe(imageResize({width : 320}))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '-320w'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imgPaths.dist))
});

gulp.task('resize-medium', function() {
    gulp.src(imgPaths.src)
    .pipe(changed(imgPaths.dist))
    .pipe(imageResize({width : 480}))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '-480w'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imgPaths.dist))
});
```

gulp resize-min or gulp resize-medium don't do anything.

Comment: `npm install --save-dev gulp-rename` maybe?

Comment: I've already installed gulp-rename. I try to run this command again and now I can see gulp-rename packge in devDependendcies but gulp resize-min and resize-medium still don't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in your `imgPaths` object is incorrect:

```
src:'./img/**/*.{jpg}',
```

What you want is:

```
src:'./img/**/*.jpg',
```

or if you have other image file formats - to capture them all:

```
src:'./img/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)',
```

Also, put return statements in your tasks like so:

```
gulp.task('resize-min', function() {
    return gulp.src(imgPaths.src)
     .pipe(changed(imgPaths.dist))
     .pipe(imageResize({width : 320}))
     .pipe(rename({suffix: '-320w'}))
     .pipe(gulp.dest(imgPaths.dist))
});
```

And the other task, you'll need the return statements sooner or later to signal to gulp when that task has completed.